# Save temporary data in cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies, fifo

I am working on a website where the I need to temporary save some strings.

Say for example I have 4 string:

```
1. hello
2. world
3. foo
4. test
```

I need to implement a FIFO (first in first out) system that means if I add a new string, the first (oldest) item should be removed. How does one implement this by using the jQuery cookie plugin?

I use the following to get/set the cookies:

```
console.log( $.cookie("test") ); //get cookie
$.cookie("test", "hello", { expires: 7, path: '/' }); //set cookie
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If possible, don't use cookies for it. In modern browsers there's a `localStorage`.

Also if you're using some kind of structures, create js structure (array, object, etc...) for it and work with it.

To save to storage (cookies), serialize this structure to string as json for example.

I propose to create js object with methods `addValue` and `getValue`, that wraps js data storage and syncs it with persistent storage silently by hooking save methods `addValue` and `setValue`.

On start you can run `init()`, that will take data from storage and deserialize it to js.

Comment: The thing is that I've never really looked into localStorage

Comment: localStorage.setItem('data','ololo'); localStorage.getItem('data'); That's all what you need about storage

Answer (score 2):

There's some code I write. It was not tested and runned, written in notepad. Just an example. Methods init and saveData can be changed for cookies.

```
   var myStorage = {
    data:[],
    init:function(){
        var json = localStorage.getItem('myData');
        if (json!=null) {
            this.data = jQuery.parseJSON(json);
        } else {
            this.data = [];
        }
    },
    addItem:function(val){
        this.data.push(val);
        this.saveData();
    },
    getItem:function(){
        var res = data[0];
        this.data = this.data.slice(1);
        this.saveData();
        return res;
    },
    saveData:function(){
        var json = JSON.stringify(this.data);
        localStorage.setItem('myData',json); 
    }


}

$(function(){
    myStorage.init();
});
```